# how to display animated gif in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to display gif in flutter.

I am using the code

```
Image(image : NetworkImage(message.image_url))
```

But it shows error:

```
Another exception was thrown: Exception: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://media.giphy.com/media/13AXYJh2jDt2IE/giphy.gif%20
```

Comment: update : i can display gifs from url "http://media2.giphy.com/media/FiGiRei2ICzzG/200_d.gif" but not from "https://media.giphy.com/media/NTY1kHmcLsCsg/giphy.gif "

Comment: This url will also work: https://giphy.com/media/FiGiRei2ICzzG/200.gif

Comment: Is this question related to Giphy website, or to a Flutter functionality to display gif?

Answer (score 93):

Place your `gif` in your images folder of your project and mention it in `pubspec.yaml` file,just like you do for images.

```
Image.asset(
  "images/loading.gif",
  height: 125.0,
  width: 125.0,
),
```

Answer (score 22):

This is what used in Flutter Gallery app to display .gif from web

```
Image.network('https://example.com/animated-image.gif')
```

Answer (score 13):

I found a way with which you can download and add giphy.com's gif in your application using @Nudge answer.

Here is the trick which you can use-

Sample Giphy's .gif URL - https://giphy.com/gifs/congratulations-congrats-xT0xezQGU5xCDJuCPe

1. You have to split the last part of url after `-`.
2. Insert the last part in the following url: `https://i.giphy.com/media/${URL_PART}/200.gif`.
3. In this case, `URL_PART` will be `xT0xezQGU5xCDJuCPe`. Simply replace it in the above url.
4. You will get the following output url:
   [https://i.giphy.com/media/xT0xezQGU5xCDJuCPe/200.gif](https://giphy.com/media/xT0xezQGU5xCDJuCPe/200.gif)

Check it out. I hope it will help someone. ;)

Comment: Wow, I will start using this a lot now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Giphy does not allow you to load the image. There's nothing that flutter can do about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: i think giphy needs an api key to access some of their gifs, something you need to pay for

Answer (score 3):

An update to @Chetan Goyal 's answer. It throws an exception of incorrect image data now.

To display URL from Giphy that looks something like `https://giphy.com/gifs/congratulations-congrats-xT0xezQGU5xCDJuCPe`, we need to extract the part after hyphen i.e. xT0xezQGU5xCDJuCPe and add it to this URL: `https://i.giphy.com/media/${URL_PART}/200.gif`

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about the changes in their url format. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new resource to assets, restart the ide

Answer (score 1):

## From assets

#### Place your gif in your images folder of your project and mention it in pubspec.yaml file,just like you do for images.

```
    Image.asset(
    "images/loading.gif",
    height: 125.0,
    width: 125.0,
),
```

## From Network

#### Use a network Image to display gif from url.

Image.network('https://example.com/animated-image.gif')