# Using an animated gif in flutter

Tags: flutter, animated-gif

I have an animated gif in my assets folder. I want to use it on my app login page but How?
I used this code:

```
          Image.asset(
            "login.gif",
            height: 125.0,
            width: 125.0,
          ),
```

but it is not doing any thing.

this is the error:

> I/flutter (31581): The following assertion was thrown resolving an
>   image codec: I/flutter (31581): Unable to load asset: login.gif

Comment: Where in the project tree is the gif stored? What does your `pubspec.yaml` assets section look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to display animated gif in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556356/how-to-display-animated-gif-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the `relative path` of the `gif` from `assets` not just the file name.

Try this..

```
Image.asset('assets/login.gif', width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
```

Also make sure that you have mentioned it in your `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the leading / in your path to the gif. It should be assets/login.gif

Also, consider using the cleaner Image.asset constructor, for example:

```
new Image.asset('assets/login.gif', width: 125.0, height: 125.0)
```