# How do i add a gif in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-android

I'm trying to add a gif from the local assets folder. Flutter throws an error named "login.gif" even though I checked multiple times if my folder structure or file name or path is correct or not or I didn't imported the path in the pubspec.yaml. But there's not a single mistake..
Tried searching for the answer everywhere but couldn't solve the issue!
I'm a complete beginner in flutter...

```
home: const Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('login.gif'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

pubspec.yaml file:

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

The Error:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service 
================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: /login.gif
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "login.gif")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#08feb(), name: 
"login.gif", scale: 1.0)
```

Comment: Show your folder structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
image: AssetImage('login.gif')
```

to

```
image: AssetImage('assets/images/login.gif')
```

If this doesn't solve your issue,

Follow this question : [how to display animated gif in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51556356/13431819)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```dart
AssetImage('assets/images/login.gif'),
```

You must include the key used in the `pubspec.yaml` to load your asset.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Image.asset("assets/images/login.gif",
                gaplessPlayback: true, fit: BoxFit.fill)
```